# Get string depending on the environment using module.exports or exports in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to NodeJs, I just couldn't find the right question, article, blog post, and whatnot about what I need to do.

Basically I want a function or a variable that returns a string for my Stripe keys based on the environment (i.e. Production and Development).

I have this in my **config.js**

```
// config.js
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

const stripeSK = function getStripeSK() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    return "a"
  } else {
    return "b"
  }
}

module.exports = {
  stripeSK: stripeSK,
  accessLevels: {
    user: "user",
    admin: "admin"
  },
  JWT_SECRET: "somesecret",
  port: process.env.PORT,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  "development": {
    "username": process.env.DEV_DB_USERNAME,...
   ...
```

But what I do get from `console.log()` is **[Function: getStripeSK]**

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `stripeSK` is assigned a function. While exporting it you need to call it and not just re-assign. For eg:

```
module.exports = {
  stripeSK: stripeSK(),
  accessLevels: {
  ...
```

Additionally, you can skip crating function entirely and can do something like this:

```
stripeSK: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'a': 'b'
```

Comment: How could I miss that ternary operators! I hate myself. Thanks for this! edit: probably I was too focused on making this function call work.

Comment: @Glenn Although this is a nice quick option but I would go with the way you are doing it right now. So, that I can have more control over the situation. I might add some other logic or maybe fetch credential from 3rd party service in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not calling the function `{ stripeSK: stripeSK, ... }` ?

It should be like this:

```
{
  stripeSK: stripeSK(),
  ...
}
```

Comment: GREAT! Funny I didn't think of that. ‍♂️ So I could just also do `  stripeSK: getStripeSK(),..` Thanks!